# Programatic manipulation of Google Map API keys

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on a MVC3 Googple maps API V3 application.

The Google Maps in my webpage gets refreshed every 10 seconds.

1) Is it possible to programatically get the number of requests/day for a Google Map API 
   key?

2) Assuming that we have used the limit of 25000 Request/Day for one API Key, is it 
   possible to programatically load and use a different, new API key from a database of API 
   keys?

Comment: its against TOS since api key's are assigned per domain. I'm sure google tracks referrer domains and IP addresses as well. 10 second intervals for 24 hr period is roughly 25k requests.

Comment: @Mike So is it possible to use multiple API keys? One user viewing  for 24 Hours will consume all the 25k requests. If a second user views it, can we load a different API key? Is there any workaround?

Comment: @AnilMaddala There is a new map load every time the maps api loader is loaded. The easiest solution is to refresh the data without refreshing the page, that way the javascript loader doesn't reload and cost a map load. You cannot use multiple keys as it would violate the TOS.

Comment: @ManoMarks How do i only refresh the map and update with the new marker positions and other data, while not registering a Map request? Could you explain in more detail or share some code or tutorial for this? Thanks.

Comment: @Mike Thanks Mike. Please correct me if I am wrong. Ajax only updates or refreshes the <div> content of the map. So once we reload the map in <div> using ajax, with the new data, wouldn't it be counted as a new request to Google Maps API?

Comment: No because you'd keep the map initialized and just change out the array of data.

Comment: @Mike Well I am pretty new to Google Maps API, can you post some code? or point to a tutorial?